# .NET: efficient way to produce a string from a Dictionary<K,V>?

Tags: .net, dictionary, extension-methods

Suppose I have a `Dictionary<String,String>`, and I want to produce a string representation of it.   The "stone tools" way of doing it would be:

```
private static string DictionaryToString(Dictionary<String,String> hash)
{
    var list = new List<String> ();
    foreach (var kvp in hash)
    {
        list.Add(kvp.Key + ":" + kvp.Value);
    }
    var result = String.Join(", ", list.ToArray());
    return result;
}
```

Is there an efficient way to do this in C# using existing extension methods?

I know about the [ConvertAll()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73fe8cwf.aspx) and [ForEach()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z.aspx) methods on List, that can be used to eliminate foreach loops. Is there a similar method I can use on Dictionary to iterate through the items and accomplish what I want?

Comment: You should set the `List`'s capacity.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In .Net 4.0:

```
String.Join(", ", hash.Select(kvp => kvp.Key + ":" + kvp.Value));
```

In .Net 3.5, you'll need to add `.ToArray()`.

Comment: Beat by a second T_T  --- good solution, quite fast and very easy to read.

Answer (score 5):

Here you go:

```
    public static class DictionaryExtensions
    {
        public static string DictionaryToString(this Dictionary<String, String> hash)
        {
            return String.Join(", ", hash.Select(kvp => kvp.Key + ":" + kvp.Value));
        }
    }
```